# Changing column references as you drag down

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[image: My Formula and columns i want to reference]

```
=SUMIFS(Intermediate!FA:FA,Intermediate!FA:FA,1,Intermediate!ACS:ACS,1)
```

I am trying to create a formula that as I drag down my sheet, only the column reference changes and goes to the right. So as I drag down rows, my reference column shifts right while keeping the same data range.

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX():

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($1:$1048576,0,ROW(1:1)-1+157),INDEX($1:$1048576,0,ROW(1:1)-1+157),1,INDEX($1:$1048576,0,ROW(1:1)-1+773),1)
```

The `ROW(1:1)-1` is the part that iterates to the next column as the row is dragged down.

The `157` and `773` are the starting column numbers for: `FA` and `ACS` respectively.

INDEX() returns the whole column as an array with the second criterion being `0` and the third criterion sets the column, using a number.

NOTE:  This can also be done with OFFSET and/or INDIRECT but those are volatile and should be avoided if possible.